# How many Killing spinors exist on $S^5$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, spinors, dirac-matrices

So, I know that on $S^n$, a spinor of the form

$$ \Sigma^\pm = \frac{1 \pm i\gamma^\alpha z_\alpha}{\sqrt{1+z^2}}\Sigma_0$$

where $\Sigma_0$ is a constant spinor, is a Killing spinor on $S^n$ because it satisfies

$$D_a \Sigma^\pm = \pm i \gamma_a \Sigma^\pm$$

where $D_a$ is the covariant derivative (with the spin connection). But how many such Killing spinors exist?

I think the $\pm$ signs yield two linearly independent solutions. But for any sign choice, there ought to be $2^{D}$ spinor components in $SO(2D)$ and $SO(2D+1)$. I am confused by the fact that the sphere is really a coset manifold: $$S^n = SO(n+1)/SO(n).$$

How does one connect spinors of $SO(n+1)$ and $SO(n)$ to those of $$S^n = SO(n+1)/SO(n)~?$$

Comment: I have been able to answer one of my questions: there are 8 Killing spinors on $S^5$. The rest of my questions are still unanswered.

Comment: There is a paper (9805151) by Lu, Pope, and  Rahmfeld discussing and constructing explicit Killing spinors on the n-sphere. I don't know if you were aware of this reference.

Comment: Hi, thanks -- yes, I am aware of it and the question was answered 3 years ago after I became aware of that paper :-).